# Creating a square pie mask in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

so I want to do something similar to this example:

http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/circlefill/

Except, I want to do it with a square instead of a circle. Is there any way to do this with AS3? Google searches provide plenty about creating a circle mask, but next to nothing regarding the pointy equivalent!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily by using the example linked above. Use the circle you create with the example above, and create a square mask for it.

```
//this is your pie from the example linked above
//it could be a MovieClip or a Sprite, or possibly another type
//but we'll just call it a DisplayObject
var pieCircle:DisplayObject;
addChild(pieCircle);

//now create a square
var squareMask:Sprite = new Sprite();
//start drawing
squareMask.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
squareMask.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, pieCircle.width/2, pieCircle.height/2);
squareMask.graphics.endFill();
addChild(squareMask);

//now set the square as a mask of the pieCircle
pieCircle.mask = squareMask;
```